# I have a 2008 cobalt that won’t start

Tags: starting, chevrolet, cobalt

I hook up the battery and the stereo comes on . When trying to start the car the accessories come on as they should then I turn the key further to start and nothing happens . I take out the keys and open the door all accessories stay on including the headlights and the only way to shut everything off is to disconnect the battery. The car has been parked inside our garage for over a month with battery disconnected. I was told it is most likely the electronic portion of the ignition $47 replaced that no difference. Checked the starter relay by switching it with another that didn’t work. Jumped the relay connections starter turns car over no problem but still does not fire up the engine . It has done this a few times but usually only for a day or so . Car has less then 110 kms on it

Comment: 110 kms or 110k kms...

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the body control module. The BCM sends a 5v ref signal out to the ignition switch and acts accordingly.  So it's not a traditional ignition switch. Try having codes pulled from the module. Unless it magically fixes it self, this more than likely isn't something you're going to be able to fix yourself.

Comment: Problem solved the breaker box under the hood hadweek connections so took it all apart cleaned and put back together. Now just hoping that is all there was to it. The breaker box wasn’t fully together I’m guessing from an accident that the car was in before we bought it. Here’s hoping and thanks for the help

Comment: If the solenoid clicks then does nothing like jumper cable bypass,  the solenoid may have condensation or oxide , no good. When fixed and then the ignition fails to give a spark to the plug, is the ignition working?